# writing tables and parameters in gams

Tags: gams-math

I am an absolute beginner in using GAMS and, although my question might seem obvious I could really use some help.

The situation is the following:

I have three sets: I,J and TR.
I is the coordinate of the origin; J is the coordinate of the destination and TR is the truck that's traveling from one place to the other.
I have a table (Trvltime_tbl(I,J)) with the Travel Time between every I and each J. I would like to create a Parameter TravelTime(I,J,TR), that contains the travel time between I and J using TR. Nevertheless the travel time is the same for each truck. How can I assign the values from the table to the parameter? I am having trouble because the table has only two dimension and the parameter has three.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

```
TravelTime(I,J,TR) = Trvltime_tbl(I,J);
```

That is, for every (I,J,TR), assign to TravelTime(I,J,TR) the value of Trvltime_tbl(I,J).